# I cannot access any github repository in google colabs

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to import a notebook from a github repository with the following github url: https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl but after hitting enter for search, the output is no result. There is similar behavior of no output if I search for anything else. There is also no difference in output when I include private repos. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: what you are trying to search?

Comment: Change the URL to `https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl.git`

Comment: For some reason things have changed and entering the URL https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl is enough to get to the files that I am looking for. I can also search by organization and user. I think reporting this issue as a bug to google colabs worked.

Comment: Actually, I think it was switching from safari to chrome that did the trick.